# Uniqueness of the evaluation isomorphism as a natural isomorphism

Tags: functional-analysis, category-theory

It is well known that the evaluation map between $V$, a topological vector space, and $V^{\star\star}$, the double dual, given by $\epsilon_{v} = f\mapsto f(v)$ is a natural isomorphism between the identity functor and the functor $(-)^{\star\star}$ in the category of real finite dimensional vector spaces or in the category of reflexive Banach spaces.

Someone once, perhaps mistakenly, told me that a topological vector space is reflexive it is naturally isomorphic to its double dual. The definition that I recall is that such a space is reflexive if the evaluation map is an isomorphism. I want to know if the previous definition is definitely wrong in a certain sense: Is it possible that for some sub-category of topological vector spaces, there is a natural isomorphism between the identity functor and the double dual functor that does not correspond to the evaluation map?

Comment: $v \mapsto(f\mapsto f(-v))$?

Comment: Huh. @HagenvonEitzen Thanks - that works, but it also wants to make me reconsider my question. I'll be back.

Comment: To elaborate on Hagen's comment, natural endomorphisms of a full subcategory including a one-dimension space are in bijection with the endomorphisms of the one-dimensional space, i.e. the multiplicative monoid of the field. Dual functors are specified up to (natural) isomorphism, so the example is still the canonical evaluation homorphism into the double dual, where the first dual is the standard one, and the second dual is an alternative one obtained from the negation isomorphism.

Answer (score 0):

I initially posted the following, but deleted it because I don't know enough about topological vector spaces. Since nobody posted an answer, I'll undelete it. Even though the comment about evaluation at $-v$ answers the question as it is asked, it doesn't invalidate the imprecise definition given to the OP. This definition was probably a mistake but some interpretation of it is still valid.

---

First, there are Banach spaces isomorphic to their double dual without being reflexive. It is the subject of James' 1951 article [*A non-reflexive Banach space isometric with its second conjugate space*](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1063327/pdf/pnas01564-0044.pdf).

But the erroneous definition says a space $V$ is reflexive if it is *naturally* isomorphic to its double dual. We will take this as meaning that there is an isomorphism $V→V^{**}$ natural with respect to all the endomorphisms of $V$. And we can prove that such a natural morphism is necessarily a multiple of the evaluation map, so if it's an isomorphism, the evaluation map too. Here is a proof. It uses the Hahn-Banach theorem, so I have no idea how badly things can go with general topological vector spaces.

Let $V$ be a Banach space and let $f : V→V^{**}\newcommand{\ev}{\operatorname{ev}}$ be a map natural in the endomorphisms of $V$. Choose $x ∈ V$ different from $0$ and choose some projector $p : V → ℝx$ which is the identity on $x$. We have $p(y) = w(y)x$ for some $w ∈ V^*$, so
$$p^*(u) = u∘p = u(x) w = \ev_x(u) w\text{.}$$
We deduce that $p^*$ is a projector on $ℝw$ and reapplying the same reasoning, $p^{**}$ is a projector on $\ev_x$ (explicitly, $p^{**}(h) = w^*(h) \ev_x$).

Since $p^{**}$ is a projector on $ℝ \ev_x$, we must have $f(x) = α \ev_x$ for some $α∈ℝ$, because $p^{**}(f(x)) = f(p(x)) = f(x)$. The goal is to prove that this $α$ is the same for all $x ∈ V$. In order to do that, let $y ∈ V$ and take $r : V→V$ defined by $r(z) = w(z) y$. Then $f(y) = f(r(x)) = r^{**}(f(x)) = r^{**}(α \ev_x) = α \ev_y$.

But I don't have very clear ideas about these duals of duals. It should be possible to explain that better...